# Ruby Geocoder connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-geocoder, rails-geocoder

When I search for an IP address, I get the following error:

```
pry(main)> Geocoder.search("130.132.173.68")
Geocoding API connection refused.
=> []
```

If I search for anything else eg.

```
pry(main)> Geocoder.search("new haven")
```

I get the correct results.
Is there a problem with the freegeoip service?

Comment: not sure if this has any importance but many of the google web services are implemented over https. Which will refuse if it cannot verify your `crt` if you are using windows I would strongly recommend the `certified` gem. Just install `gem install certified` and then `require certified` in the files where you are making these calls and see if it changes anything.

Comment: *Revision* I have no idea why this is happening because when I run your OP verbatim it works fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure you use Google for IP lookup?

Comment: Yes, I believe the IP lookup uses freegeoip

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an initializer setup for Geocoder with all of the config settings. This was the problem for me. Something along the lines like this:

# config/initializers/geocoder.rb

```
Geocoder.configure(  
 # geocoding options
 :timeout      => 7,           # geocoding service timeout (secs)
 :lookup       => :google,     # name of geocoding service (symbol)
 :language     => :en,         # ISO-639 language code
 :use_https    => true,        # use HTTPS for lookup requests? (if supported)
 :http_proxy   => '',          # HTTP proxy server (user:pass@host:port)
 :https_proxy  => '',          # HTTPS proxy server (user:pass@host:port)
 :api_key      => nil,         # API key for geocoding service
 :cache        => nil,         # cache object (must respond to #[], #[]=, and #keys)
 :cache_prefix => "geocoder:", # prefix (string) to use for all cache keys

 # IP address geocoding service (see below for supported options):
 #:ip_lookup => :maxmind,

 # to use an API key:
 #:api_key => "...",

 # exceptions that should not be rescued by default
 # (if you want to implement custom error handling);
 # supports SocketError and TimeoutError
 # :always_raise => [],

 # calculation options
 # :units     => :mi,       # :km for kilometers or :mi for miles
 # :distances => :linear    # :spherical or :linear
)
```